# atTask and AngularJS CORS header pass cookie auth

Tags: angularjs, cors, attask

atTask's developer forum directed me here.

How do I setup my AngularJS controller's `$http.get` to access atTask's search api `mydomain/attask/api/projects/search` if the user is already logged in, in that browser?

I started with:

```
var atTaskTA = angular.module('atTaskTA', []);

atTaskTA.config(function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

atTaskTA.controller('atTaskTAController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data = "unknown";
    $http.get("https://mydomain.com/attask/api/project/search").success(function(data){
        console.log("Success", data);
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}]);
```

I am not familiar with setting up a header to pass the cookie info for authentication which I believe is what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

See the angular docs for the $http service [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).  In particular look at the section on interceptors, where you can add headers to the request before it is transmitted.

In particular you can modify the request object like so:

```
    $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, ...) { 

        request: function (config) {
           config.headers["my-custom-header"] = myCustomHeaderValue;
           return config || $q.when(config);

    ...
    }

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```